# VueJS - invalid rendering of feather icons

Tags: javascript, vue.js, feathericons

I have an application where I try to render feather-icons (in the menu and in some part of the application).

The problem is when I click on some anchor tag and route myself to another component, the icons will disappear until I hit "refresh (F5)" .. after that they appear fine.

Is there something I am missing? Do I have to "force" reload for each route?

Here are the files:

**index.html** - here I am importing the feather icons

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>My App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>Sorry, this app doesn't work without javascript enabled!</noscript>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="/dist/build.js"></script>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/feather-icons/4.9.0/feather.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

when I load the main page - everything is fine ... but when I "route" to other page/compoment it disappears until I refresh/reload (F5) the page

**routes.js**

```
import Home from './components/Home.vue'
import Login from './components/Login.vue'
import NotFound from './components/generic/404.vue'


import Customer from './components/admin/Customer.vue'
import AddCustomer from './components/admin/AddCustomer.vue'

export const routes = [
  { path: "", name: 'home', component: Home},
  { path: "/login", name: 'login', component: Login},

// customers
  { path: "/customers", name: 'customers', component: Customer},
  { path: "/add-customer", name: 'add-customer', component: AddCustomer},

 // 404
  { path: "/not-found", name: 'not-found', component: NotFound},
  { path: "*", redirect: { name: 'not-found'}},
]
```

here is my add-customer

```
<template lang="html">
  <div class="main">
    <tw-navbar></tw-navbar>

    <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
       <tw-sidebar></tw-sidebar>

         <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4">
            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
              <div class="container">
                <h1 class="h2">Add new customer</h1>
                <form class="w-50 m-auto">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="username">Username</label>
                  <input type="username" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter username">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="password">Password</label>
                  <div class="input-group mb-2 mr-sm-2">
                    <input type="password" class="form-control"
                            id="password" placeholder="Password"
                            v-model="password">
                    <div class="input-group-append">
                      <div class="input-group-text">
                        <span data-feather="eye" v-if="isVisible"></span>
                        <span data-feather="eye-off" v-if="!isVisible"></span>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
              </div>
            </div>
         </main>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import Navbar from './../navigation/Navbar.vue'
  import Sidebar from './../navigation/Sidebar.vue'
  import CustomerService from './../../services/CustomerService'
  import generator from './../../helpers/generator'

    export default {
      data() {
        return {
          username: null,
          password: null,
          passwordAgain: null,
          nameFirst: null,
          nameLast: null,
          email: null,
          isVisible: false,
        }
      },
      components: {
        'tw-navbar': Navbar,
        'tw-sidebar': Sidebar,
      },
      methods: {
      },
      mounted() {
      }
    }
</script>

<style lang="css" scoped>
</style>
```

when I check the source code.. it does not render the SVG until I hit the F5

based on this [thread](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/cant-trigger-click-on-svg-with-feather/48714/13) it seems feather icons are not compatible with VUE :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to include some third party package its always good to search for an vue.js compatible package

There is `vue-feather-icons` package extra made for vue

```
npm i vue-feather-icons
```

Then you can simply use it as components:

You need to use pascal case and you need to write `Icon` and the end

```
import { EyeIcon } from "vue-feather-icons";
components: {
   EyeIcon
}
```

You can put an style on it, you can add classes to it, you can do whatever you want with it. It also has this prop called `size` where you can set the size of the icon

```
<EyeIcon size="2x" />
```

https://vue-feather-icons.egoist.sh/